# How to design a custom image filter for edge detection?

Tags: image-processing

Consider a sample image `img` as

[image]

If I apply a `GradientFilter` on it followed by a padding,

```
imggrad = GradientFilter[img,1];
gradpadded = ImagePad[imggrad,1];
```

Now I want to design a custom `3x3` max filter to detect the edges. The plan is to place the filter at the top left corner of the `gradpadded`(at the position `(1,1)`) and apply the filter on the first `3x3` image data. Next, I wish to find the position of the maximum value within the selected data. After that, the filter will be centered at that corresponding maximum value position and will be applied on the corresponding image portion. This process will carry on until the filter reaches the end of the image or returns back to an earlier position and thus completing a loop.

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at `ImageConvolve` and at `MaxFilter`...Moreover, it seems you already know how to do it. I mean, you know how to devise the kernel of the max filter you need. Just read the functions cited, particularly the first one...

Comment: You should probably start by reading the [image processing tutorial in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImageProcessing.html). Then browse the list of image processing functions, and you should be able to do most of these things. If not, come back and revise this question. As it is, it's way too broad IMO

Answer (score 1):

It could be a starting point by using `MaxFilter` of different sizes:

```
ImageAssemble[ImageSubtract[MaxFilter[img, #], img] & /@ Table[{i, i}, {i, 3}]]
```

[image]